# CSS - Problema con Overlay

Tags: css, reactjs

Mi consulta es sobre que me genera conflicto para poder lograr que el overlay para poder tomar el 100% de la pantalla y o quizas lo que esta descentrado el componente del que es el circulo de carga , pero no logro entender que evita que el overlay del componente loader no logre ocupar toda la pantalla.

```
---------------Este es el css de mi overlay---------
.overlay{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

---------Desde esta parte es el Loader Spinner de la libreria Pure CSS loader-----
.lds-roller {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 30%;
}
.lds-roller div {
  animation: lds-roller 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
  transform-origin: 40px 40px;
}
.lds-roller div:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #000000;
    margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.036s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(1):after {
  top: 63px;
  left: 63px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.072s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(2):after {
  top: 68px;
  left: 56px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.108s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(3):after {
  top: 71px;
  left: 48px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -0.144s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(4):after {
  top: 72px;
  left: 40px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: -0.18s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(5):after {
  top: 71px;
  left: 32px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: -0.216s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(6):after {
  top: 68px;
  left: 24px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: -0.252s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(7):after {
  top: 63px;
  left: 17px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: -0.288s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(8):after {
  top: 56px;
  left: 12px;
}

@keyframes lds-roller {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


--------------Mi componente Loader.js-------------
import './loader.css'

function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <div className='overlay'>
          <div className="lds-roller">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default BasicExample;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Lo otro que estaba pensado es sobre el valor del display en ambas clases , tanto la del overlay como la del roll pure css , quizas eso este afectando la forma en que toma la pantalla.

Unas imagenes de ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya muchas gracias por darme una mano a quien me pueda ayudar

Comment: Tu pregunta no tiene la suficiente información, entiendes que quiere decir width:100%??

Comment: Que informacion puedo agregar a la pregunta que puede estar faltando ?

Comment: width:100% es el hancho del area del contenido que va a mostrar , en este caso el overlay deberia ocupar el 100% de su del hancho , lo mismo para la altura con height:100% , mi idea era ocupar todo el hancho y el alto de la pantalla con overlay  , pero como se ve en la imagen falta una seccion de abajo y no logro decifrar el por que

Comment: No estimado, 100% es una medida relativa. relativa a quién ??? a su padre...a cualquier padre? tampoco. Es relativa al primer padre que encuentre que tenga `position: algo` seteado. Si ningún padre tiene position seteado llega hasta la etiqueta HTML y recién ahí podría ocupar el 100% del área visible, con los top, left, etc también pasa lo mismo. Entonces para determinar la causa de tu problema es necesario conocer los padres, porque ellos afectan directamente. Entonces a lo menos falta información de la estructura del HTML del overlay hasta sus padres y todos los CSS de ellos

Comment: Y por sobre todo tienes que generar un [MRE], algo donde se pueda ver error en vivo y en directo, de lo contrario es jugar a las adivinanzas

Comment: ahora genero un ejemplo minimo verificable

Comment: gracias  Yussef pude solucionar mi problema , era cuestion de entender sobre la posicion del componente como bien estabas explicando en tu comentario mas arriba , voy a tratar de ser mas cuidadoso y agregar ejemplos minimos desde ahora en mas , gracias

Comment: Me alegro mucho se haya resuelto, yo sospechaba que lo ibas a resolver cuando trataras de generar el [MRE]. Suerte en el proyecto!!